# new created virtualenv not being activated but old

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm working with a django project with virtualenv. I needed to create a new virtualenv for another project. and I've did that. but while I was trying to activate new virtualenv, it show that my old virtualenv is being activate.

My request to you- why this? and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you deactivated your old virtual env? Please update the question with commands that you are using to activate your `env`?

Comment: yes. I've deactivated my old virtualenv first & then tried to activate new one

Comment: As Qubad said, you need to show the commands you are using. See also my article on virtualenvs, http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/

Comment: Did you just copy the old virtualenv directory to a new place?

Comment: yes, @AndreyShipilov

Comment: There's your answer. You don't do this. You create a new one and install all the dependencies in it.

Comment: your're right @AndreyShipilov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! it was for my mistake. I'd copied my old virtualenv folder and files and pasted into another location of course with a different name of the root folder. just like this:

my old virtualenv root folder's name is **project1**

my new folder where copied all files & folders from **project1** is  **project2**

I've deactivated virtualenv. & entered **project2** folder an tried to activate environment using this command

`source bin/activate`

it show me this line:

```
(project1) username@computername ~/Desktop/project2 $
```

if everything is okay then It will show me this line instead:

```
(project2) username@computername ~/Desktop/project2 $
```

and I could solve this problem following these steps:
first do delete **project2** and again create a new folder and rename as you wish (here. I keep **project2**) and enter the folder and go to terminal with located this folder. and type:

```
virtualenv .
```

then new virtualenv will be created. now activate **project2** with this command:

```
source bin/activate
```

now you'll get your new virtualenv (**project2**) activated.

```
(project2) username@computername ~/Desktop/project2 $
```

> thanks Quabad for trying to help me.